# jQuery .click() not consistently working on Safari

Tags: jquery, safari, fadein, fadeout

I have an overlay effect on a site that appears when anyone activates a modal video player. The `.click()` to make the dark overlay appear works on all browsers, but the `.click()` to make it disappear works on all but Safari.

Here is the code being used:

```
$("a.watch-video").click(function() {
    $('#superhomevideooverlay').fadeIn();
});

$("a.video-close").click(function() {
    $('#superhomevideooverlay').fadeOut();
});
```

And the overlay's CSS is

```
#superhomevideooverlay {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #000;
  filter: alpha(opacity=50);
  -moz-opacity: 0.5;
  -khtml-opacity: 0.5;
  opacity: 0.5;
  z-index: 1000;
  display: none;
}
```

JS Fiddle example: http://jsfiddle.net/Zf9Bp/
Note: On JSF, it works in Safari. So I'm even more stumped.

Comment: Can you reproduce this on jsFiddle.net?

Comment: Fiddle added. The Fiddle works on Safari, but my live site does not. Go figure.

Comment: adjusted answer to your version of jQuery, give it a try ...

Comment: Apologies, but the fiddle is not accurate in that sense. That is the lowest jquery I could use on Fiddle without linking externally. This site actually uses 1.4.4.

Comment: using version 1.4.4 http://jsfiddle.net/djHgp/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just out of curiosity, try the following and tell me if it works. Replace both `.click` methods with this one:

```
$(document).delegate('a.watch-video, a.video-close', 'click', function(e) {
    if ($(this).hasClass('watch-video')) {
        $('#superhomevideooverlay').fadeIn();
    }
    else if ($(this).hasClass('video-close')) {
        $('#superhomevideooverlay').fadeOut();
    }
})
```

## Example

---

Tested and working on Safari versions 4.1 and 5.1

Comment: @user1729506 did you remove the other 2 `.click` events? This should work if you're using same jQuery version I saw in fiddle.

Comment: I did, but the live site is using 1.4.4.

Comment: @user1729506 I just tested this code locally using Safari version 4 on an old mac and it worked just fine, fyi. There may be another error in your code. check your developer console log for errors